# Python 3.x: My function returns 'TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have a function all_word_pairs (which gets all words from all .txt files from the same directory and creates a list of lists containing two elements: the word itself and the file from which it originates) and it's defined like this:

```
def all_word_pairs():
"""Return list of word + filename tuples from .txt files in current directory"""
# collect .txt filenames
filenames = []
# scan all files in current directory
for f in os.listdir("."):
    # test if f ends with .txt
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
        # yes it does, so add it to filenames
        filenames.append(f)
# collect word pairs from all filenames
return word_pairs(filenames)
```

[This is what print(all_word_pairs()) will return.](http://i.imgur.com/4sZUHa2.jpg)

Now I build a function to sort the lists (within the list given by the all_word_pairs function) by their first element (the retrieved word):

```
def merge_pairs(data):
if len(data) <= 1:
    res = data
    return res

else:   
    res = []
    fi = 0
    si = 0
    imid = len(data) // 2
    fst = merge_pairs(data[:imid])
    snd = merge_pairs(data[imid:])
    while fi <= len(fst)-1 and si <= len(snd) - 1:
        if fst[fi][0] < snd[si][0]:
            res.append(fst[fi])
            fi = fi + 1
        else:
            res.append(snd[si])
            si = si + 1
    if fi <= len(fst) - 1:
            res.extend(fst[fi:])
    elif si <= len(snd) - 1:
        res.extend(snd[si:])

i = 0
while i < len(res) - 1:
    while res[i][1] == res[i + 1][1]:
        res[i], res[i + 1] = res[i + 1], res[i]
    i = i + 1
return res
```

When I call the function merge_pairs it gives me a TypeError: objectof the type 'function' has no len(). [This is what it looks like.](http://i.imgur.com/OMhrEuG)

Does anyone know what goes wrong? I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You are calling `merge_pairs` with *the function `all_word_pairs`* as an argument, as the error message tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing:

```
print(merge_pairs(all_merge_pairs))
```

This passes in the *function* `all_merge_pairs` as `data`, not its result.

You need to do:

```
print(merge_pairs(all_merge_pairs()))
```

Comment: it is python 3 so your print would cause another error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fixed; it's a habit.  Though now it basically screams to be broken up over multiple lines!

Comment: yep, not a major issue but chances are it might have ended up the OP's next question  ;)